# function print_embed_scripts() - WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, embed

I edited the wp-includes/embed.php file

I changed the code for the site title area from .wp-embed-site-title{display:table-cell} to .wp-embed-site-title{display:none}

It did exactly what I wanted, removed the site title from the link I embedded. Please see screenshot  http://grab.by/S2J4 ... where it says "site title area" the code removed it! Which is the goal, I don't want the additional information at the bottom.

However, I know not to edit the core files so I copied the file to my theme, but it didn't work.

My question is, what is the correct folder to copy it to?

The folder I copied it to was wp-content/themes/my-theme

Thank you in advance for any help!